# What is "spin" in spin representations?

Tags: string-theory, representation-theory

When finding representations of Lorentz algebra let's say so(1,D-1), we can find some representations of this algebra using the Clifford algebra. I understand how to identify Weyl and Majorana representations using the Dirac representations. But the representations that we find in this way are called spin $\frac{1}{2}$ representations. But there are spin $1$, spin $\frac{3}{2}$ representations etc. Simply my question is what does mean to say spin $\frac{3}{2}$ representation , spin $\frac{1}{2}$ representation etc?

Comment: It boils down to Theorem 2 in [this thesis](https://www.phy.uniri.hr/~ivukovic/su(2)IRREPs.pdf) that all irreducible representations of $su(2)$ are completely determined by the half integers $\ell=0,\frac{1}{2},1,\frac{3}{2}\dots\,.$ What this "well-known" fact has to do with physics is a little bit explained [here](https://sharif.edu/~sadooghi/QFT-I-96-97-2/LorentzPoincareMaciejko.pdf).

Comment: These [two](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2192198/949989) [posts](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/607228/304394) show concretely how the spin 1/2, 1 and 3/2 representations look like.

Comment: From a strictly mathematical point of view, the “spin” $s$ is just an alternate way of specifying the *dimensionality* of the representation: $d=2s+1$. Showing that $s$ has something to do with angular momentum in QFT is… not as conceptually simple.

Comment: @KurtG. Thank you for the response. In the case of su(2), which is isomorphic to the lie algebra of spin(3), i understand the meaning of spin. But this is used in higher dimensional cases as well. As an example when considering spin(8) lie-algebra (In superstring theory with regards to massless irreps) again I have seen using the words spin 1/2, 3/2 etc , but with no clear explanation. Could you give me an answer in the case of spin(8)=so(8) lie algebra?

Comment: I wish I could. This [MO post](https://mathoverflow.net/q/407879/340165) could help you further.

Comment: It's not really about dimension. Spin 0 and 1/2 are definitions. After that, you count how many tensor products of spin 1/2 with itself are needed to get the desired irrep.